# how to get a session value set inside the application folder in an external file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I set a session variable

```
($_SESSION['ses_dashid']="xxx";)
```

Inside controller in  application folder using codeignter.I need this session variable outside the application folder.How can be make it possible using PHP?

I used the following code

```
        ob_start();
        include('index.php');
        ob_end_clean();
        $CI =& get_instance();
        //$CI->load->library('session'); //if it's not autoloaded in your CI setup
        $publval=$CI->session->userdata('ses_dashid');
```

but after this code other values can't be access.How can we resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below, if you are using Codeigniter then use codeigniter session libraray 
Example: 
In Controller

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
                            'user_id'       => $user->uid,
                            'username'      => $user->username,

                    ));
```

and you can get it like this:

```
$user_id                   = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$username                     = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: `OP` want to something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can get session value anywhere, inside application folder

syntex is :

```
 $sessionval = $this->session->userdata('Your_session_Name');
 //if its a sting 
 echo $sessionval; 
 // if array than 
 print_r($sessionval);
```

Comment: He specifically mentioned he wanted to access it outside the `application` folder